# Undrop or Timetravel in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, time-travel

I got this question today in an interview and I answered snowpipe but not sure if its right..Is there any object in snowflake that cant be undrop or any object that cant use time travel features!

I tried searching snowflake documentations but no mention of it!

Comment: View(if tried to be recovered separately and not part of schema/database), virtual warehouse, resource monitor, role, ...

Comment: I thought a replaced table, also could not be time travelled, as the new table does not have "that time"

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim if by replaced you mean creating TableA, dropping TableA and then creating another table called TableA, you can undrop the original table but only by renaming the current TableA first

Comment: @NickW ok, shows how little I drop tables, but I was think with respect of time travel. But if they are undropped, then time travel, could in theory work again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on snowflake since 4 years, and If I would be in place of Interviewer, I would expect the answer Snowflake stage.Snowflake stage is one of core component in data loading, ETL. (And because time travel is mainly for data and stage is object which holds data but still don't support undrop).

Snowflake stage is one of core component in data loading, ETL. But it does not support the undrop.

But there might be other objects as well for sure.

[image]

Also File format do not suppport Undrop

[image]